# Extract a Flickr photo ID from URL

Tags: php, regex

I need to extract a piece of a URL in PHP. From the URL `http://www.flickr.com/photos/28370443@N08/7885410582` I need only the `7885410582` part.

My code:

```
$string2 = 'http://www.flickr.com/photos/28370443@N08/7885410582';
preg_match_all('~s/ (.*?) /~i',$string2,$matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
echo $matches[1][0] . '<br />';
```

Can anyone look at it and correct it for me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
$data = explode("/",$url)
$value = $data[sizeof($data)-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this regex:

```
\d+$
```

will find all digits before string end

or:

```
(?<=/)\d+$
```

will find all digits after `/` sign before string end

Answer (score 0):

If the identifier you want is always the last in the URL, don't bother with regular expressions and instead use simple string functions.

```
<?php

$url = 'http://www.flickr.com/photos/28370443@N08/7885410582';

$flickr_id = substr($url, strrpos($url, "/") + 1);

echo $flickr_id; // 7885410582
```

Comment: Should be the fastest solution of all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
preg_match_all('~^.+/(\d+)$~',$string2,$matches);
```

#### Description

[image: Regular expression visualization]

#### Demo

http://regex101.com/r/aL2hL3

#### Sample code

```
$string2 = 'http://www.flickr.com/photos/28370443@N08/7885410582';
preg_match('~^.+/(\d+)$~',$string2,$matches);
echo  $matches[1]; // 7885410582
```